# How to kill basic authentication request from browser

Tags: html, browser

User open the index page presented with basic browser authentication, but he doesn't respond and provides username/password. 
In this scenario, I want to kill that http request, is there any way of doing it. I remember we can set a timeout cookie but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Would `window.stop();` work? There's a way to cancel an ajax request using `<object>.abort();` but I don't think that will help you in your situation.

Comment: Using window.stop() means I need to maintain a timer, which seems a hack. I am assuming there might be some in browser support(using header, meta tag) for this, which kills outgoing request after certain time

Comment: I think that would have to be server side.